# Find the last digit of user input and do something with it

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python program that the while loop stops when the input's last digit is 2 or 7 and prints out how many numbers they entered.

So for example, if the player enters:

```
Enter an integer: 21
Enter an integer: 5
Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: 27
4 <- returns 4 since the player only entered 4 inputs.
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
def count_inputs():
    num = 0
    count = 0
    while num[-1] == '2' or num[-1] == '7':
        num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: @JohnGordon Yep I did. I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I am only allowed to edit that one while line only. I have tried (num % 10 != 2 and num % 10 != 7) and that also doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: `while num % 10 != 2 and num % 10 != 7:` works for me with the sample input above.

Comment: Works great with positive numbers but not with negative numbers. 
Currently trying to find a solution @JohnGordon

Comment: You could use `abs(num)` to ensure the numbers are positive.

Comment: If you execute the code **exactly** as shown, nothing will happen. If you add code to invoke your *count_inputs()* function you will get a TypeError exception because Python integer types are not subscriptable

Comment: What if the input is 2 or -7? Should it stop?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your loop condition is reversed. Your program continues as long as the last digit *is* 2 or 7, rather than stopping at that time.

```
while num[-1] != '2' and num[-1] != '7':
```

Now, you can't use brackets to index into an integer, only a string. In your case, since you never actually do anything numerical to the input, you can forego the `int` conversion entirely.

```
num = input("Enter an integer: ")
```

Or, if you still want to input integers (for example, if there's more arithmetic to your actual program that you haven't shown here), you can convert it back to a string for the checks.

```
num = '0'
count = 0
while str(num)[-1] == '2' or str(num)[-1] == '7':
    ...
```

Finally, getting the last digit in particular of a number can be done by taking that number modulo 10. Put another way, the last digit of a number (in base 10) is equal to the remainder after we divide that number by 10. So we can simply write

```
while num % 10 not in [2, 7]:
```

Note: If you're planning to accept negative numbers as well, you'll need to take an `abs`olute value for this trick to work.

```
while abs(num) % 10 not in [2, 7]:
```

Comment: The last digit of -7 isn't 3...

Comment: @KellyBundy Curses! The one time that the C-style "match dividend" modulo would actually be useful. Added a note to the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The string method `endswith` accepts a tuple of possibilities. You could use that to satisfy your `while` condition. Also, your condition seems to be backwards. You want the loop to run while `num` does not end with 2 or 7.

```
def count_inputs():
    num   = ''
    count = 0
    while not num.endswith(('2', '7')):
        num = input("Enter an integer: ")
        count += 1
    return count
    
print(count_inputs())
```

If you wanted to do this where `num` is an integer, you can use modulus. However, not a modulus of 10 but, a modulus of 5. This will make `2` or `7` just `2`, reducing this to 1 condition.

```
def count_inputs():
    count = 0
    while int(input("Enter an integer: ")) % 5 != 2:
        count += 1
    return count
    
print(count_inputs())
```

Comment: Holy obscure corner cases, Batman! I didn't believe you when you said `endswith` could take a tuple, but here we are. I wonder what led to support for such arguments...

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - I didn't know it either 10 minutes ago. I learned a while back to check docs on all built-ins that I never use when recommending them in an answer. They almost always have some extra argument or something that turns out to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Why doesn't this work? ..."*

Firstly, there is a syntax error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python/example.py", line 9, in <module>
    count_inputs()
  File "/python/example.py", line 4, in count_inputs
    while num[-1] == '2' or num[-1] == '7':
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The term *subscriptable* refers to the bracket notation, `[ ]`.

You would need to parse *num* first, using the *[str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)* *built-in function*.

```py
str(num)[-1] in ['2', '7']
```

Another problem with your code is that *num* is assigned the *input* value from within the *while-loop*.
Use a *boolean* to determine when to exit the *loop*.

```py
def count_inputs():
    count = 0
    exit = False
    while not exit:
        num = input("Enter an integer: ")
        if num[-1] in ['2', '7']: exit = True
        count += 1
    return count
```

Output

```
Enter an integer: 21
Enter an integer: 5
Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: 27
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking the user to input an integer it's a good idea to make sure that they enter an integer

```
def count_inputs():
    count = 0
    while True:
        v = input('Enter an integer: ')
        try:
            int(v)
            count += 1
            if v[-1] in '27':
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return count

print(count_inputs())
```